# Ceph-ansible: using the OS-SSD as cache

Tags: ansible, ceph

In ceph-ansible, you can specify a disk to be used for databases in the `hosts` file using the `dedicated_devices` directory. Example:

```
hosts:
    stor01.hostname.com
        devices: ['/dev/sdd', '/dev/sde', '/dev/sdf']
        dedicated_devices: ['/dev/sdc']
```

Here `sdc` is an SSD drive which will be used for the rocksdb database. It should be at least 1% of the total size of the hard drives for this to work.

However, what if my OS is already on the SSD drive I intend to use? Let's say that this is a large SSD drive with a small OS partition and several empty partitions, one for each 1TB HDD. E.g. the config is:

```
/dev/sda
..sda1 40GB ext4 OS (mounted: /)
..sda2 20GB xfs (unmounted)
..sda3 20GB xfs (unmounted)
(etc)
/dev/sdb (unpartitioned, 1TB)
/dev/sdc (unpartitioned, 1TB)
(etc).
```

Essentially I don't want ansible to go and format the drive, but I do want it to set the already pre-formatted partitions as the location of the db file. How do I achieve this?